# Excel Index Match Query

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the table on the right, below, with the dates as well as information tagged with them. I want to show/list all the tagged info with the corresponding dates, without using pivot table, since I'm planning to pull the information from another sheet that is a master list. What kind of formula should I use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I originally misread your question - you have the data on the right and you want to convert it to the data on the left? I am no pro, but the way I would do it is as shown in the pic [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwmGc.png) (I don't have enough rep to post pictures inline).

Essentially, I created a couple of helper indices on the left, the first tracks the current row position which increments if there is data to be had, otherwise it resets to zero:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(data,A3+1,B3)<>"",A3+1,1),1)
```

The IFERROR is just because I had a named array (data) that has a limit and I didn't want to check if that limit had been reached. A3 is the reference to the previously used row that is right above the current cell while B3 is a reference to the previously used column (above and to the right).

The column index formula just takes the current row and, if it is 1 that means we have started a new column so take the previously used column and add 1, otherwise we stick to the same column.

```
=IF(A4=1,B3+1,B3)
```

The date column just takes the current column index and gets it using "index"

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(dates,1,B4),"")
```

The value column just takes the row and column indices and pops out the value from the table:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(data,A4,B4),"")
```

The initial indices for row/column are set to 1 to begin, the remainder are auto-generated. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Power Query.

Select a cell in the range and click the Data Ribbon > From Table (or, for earlier versions of Excel than 2016, install the Power Query add-in and click Power Query ribbon > From Table). Then

- Tick the box for "My Table has Headers" and OK.
- When the data opens in the Power Query Editor, click Add Column > Index.
- Select the newly created index column and click Transform > Unpivot Other Columns

The data now shows normalised and you can add commands to sort, rename the columns and finally remove the index column, which is no longer required. Then save the query to load the data into a spreadsheet. When your original data changes, you can refresh the query to update the normalised list.

[image]